# Which Nokia devices can Qt-based applications be deployed on?

Tags: qt, nokia

Can applications developed using the Qt framework be deployed in all the Nokia devices?

And Series 40, Series 60, Maemo cover all the Nokia devices available? How can we identify that an Qt application can be deployed on a Nokia device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say, the application should run on any device, where you are able to install the required Qt and QtMobility backend (until today the backend is not built into the operating system... although I would guess that this will be the case with the new MeeGo devices - but that's really just a guess).

Comment: Thanks Cyphories. Could you please tell us how to identify that device is supporting QT apps? is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take this as a reference: http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/

Shortly I would say: it will not run on Series 40, but on all S60, Maemo and MeeGo Devices.
It might be, that some features only run - for example - on devices with S60 5th Ed. but not on S60 3rd Ed. devices... but I never ran across this problem.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, Qt runs on S60 platforms from 3rd Edition FP1 (3.1) onwards. See the [device matrix on Forum Nokia](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/matrix_all_1.html) to see which devices have S60 3.1 or newer. In practice, some devices may have compatibility or resource (in particular, memory) issues. To be sure, you'll have to test on all devices you want to officially support.

Also, Qt is available on Maemo 5 devices (N900). Qt 4.6.2 is preinstalled on N900 PR 1.2 software update.

Series 40 is not supported.

In any case, the *same* application cannot be deployed on both S60 and Maemo. You'll have to build and package it for each platform.